# Why isn't "are" placed at the end of the question in "Have you ever wondered who the people ARE you see every day...?"

Tags: questions, word-order, embedded-clauses

I've been reading an advanced level English book where I came across this sentence in an introduction to one of its articles:

*Have you ever wondered who the people **are** you see every day on the way to work?*

As far as I know, in similar questions like the one above, if there is an auxiliary verb, it should be placed at the end of the sentence (indirect questions); however, this structure is quite new to me. Is there a reason why?

Comment: It would be perfectly possible to put the _are_ at the end, but that would make a long gap in the phrase 'who the people are'. The writer has made a stylistic choice, so as to make the sentence read better.

Comment: @Kate Bunting: So, from a grammatical point of view, is the word order correct?

Comment: I don't see why not. If I had thought it was wrong I would have said so.

Answer (score 2):

> Have you ever wondered *who* **the people you see every day on the way to work** *are*?

It's the pattern I commonly see and expect. However, as Kate Bunting pointed out, the long noun phrase *the people you see every day on the way to work* can make this indirect question more difficult to read. It's a stylistic choice.

To make the sentence structure (doubtfully) clearer, you can put either *that* or *who* after *are*.

> Have you ever wondered *who* **the people** *are* [that/who*] you see every day on the way to work?

*It feels a bit repetitive with two *who*s closely positioned.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer! +1